# Validate header row of table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scroll, rspec, cucumber, watir

So i'm trying to grab a row a of table headers off a page:

```
 header_row = @page.send('header_row_element')
 headers = header_row.ths.collect { |th| th.text }
  table_of_elements.raw.flatten.each do |option|
    expect(headers).to include option
  end

Note: table_of_elements is coming from a Cucumber Table ie:
   | value         |
   | another value |
   | etc           |
```

I'm having no problem finding the header row on the page and returning the values but my problem is that the table is in a **scroll window**

So the code `headers = header_row.ths.collect { |th| th.text }`is returning an array with only the headers that are within the view of the current location of the scroll: 
headers = [ "value", "another value", "", "" ]

I can't seem to handle the side scrolling window to get the other headers in view. I've tried **RAutomation**, **send_keys**, nothing seems to work. I'm not sure why the `ths.collect` method wont return all the values regardless of visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the scroll window is implemented will impact whether detect the text as visible or not. For example, some scroll windows set the overflow text to be hidden, which will result in Selenium/Watir seeing no text. I believe it was some of the DevExtreme controls where I ran into this.

If there are no tags within the `th` elements, the easiest solution is to gather the inner HTML instead. This will allow you to bypass the visibility checks:

```
headers = header_row.ths.collect { |th| th.inner_html }
```

Comment: so this returns my headers as:

'["<div style=\"text-align: left; width: 100px;\"> header value </div>",  "next value" .... ]'

this does seem to solve the visibility checks and is returning the whole header row, but I thought that 'th.inner_html' would just be the text

Comment: Ah figured it out. Each 'th' had a 'div' within it. Changed:
**header_row.ths.collect** to **header_row.divs.collect**